# Interpretation of log-transformed (simple) regression models - confirmation requested

Tags: regression, interpretation, regression-coefficients, logarithm

I am ashamed to admit I never questioned this while obtaining my bachelor's in statistics but it's coming up again in grad school and I'm now realizing that I've been using approximations for interpreting regression coefficients for log-transformed models.

**What I've been taught**

1. Level-log $\hat{Y} = \beta_0 + \beta_1\ln(X)$ - a 1% increase in the independent variable yields a $\beta_0/100$ unit change in the dependent variable.
2. Log-level $\ln(\hat{Y}) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X$ - a 1 unit increase in the independent variable yields a $\exp(\beta_1) - 1\times 100$ percent change in the dependent variable
3. Log-log $\ln(\hat{Y}) = \beta_0 + \beta_1\ln(X)$ - a 1% change in the independent variable yields a $\beta_1$ percent change in the dependent variable

**Today's revelations**
I finally sat down and did the math as a sudden suspicion hit me. Can someone verify that my suspicions are correct? Apologies for the unaligned equations; I could not figure out how to use the align environment on here.

1. Level-log

$$ y = \beta_1\ln(x) + \beta_0 $$
$$ y + h = \beta_1\ln(1.01x) + \beta_0 $$
$$ y + h = \beta_1\ln(x) + \beta_1\ln(1.01) + \beta_0 $$
$$ y + h = y + \beta_1\ln(1.01) $$
$$ h = \beta_1\ln(1.01) $$

So approximating with a $\beta_1/100$ is reasonable for a 1% change but for an arbitrary % change $p$ it'd be more appropriate to use $\beta_1\ln(1+p/100)$

2. Log-level

$$ \ln(y) = \beta_1 x + \beta_0 $$
$$ \ln(y+h) = \beta_1 (x+1) + \beta_0 $$
$$ \ln(y+h) = \beta_1 x + \beta_1 + \beta_0 $$
$$ \ln(y+h) = \ln(y) + \beta_1 $$
$$ \ln(y+h) - \ln(y) = \beta_1 $$
$$ \ln(y+h / y) = \beta_1 $$
$$ \ln(1+h/y) = \beta_1 $$
$$ 1 + h/y = \exp(\beta_1) $$
$$ h/y = \exp(\beta_1) - 1 $$

Ok, so this one is right and not just an approximation.

3. Log-log

$$ \ln(y) = \beta_1 \ln(x) + \beta_0 $$
$$ \ln(y+h) = \ln(1.01x) + \beta_0 $$
$$ \ln(y+h) = \beta_1\ln(x) + \beta_1\ln(1.01) + \beta_0 $$
$$ \ln(y+h) = \ln(y) + \beta_1\ln(1.01) $$
$$ \ln(y+h) - ln(y) = \beta_1\ln(1.01) $$
$$ \ln(y+h / y) = \beta_1\ln(1.01) $$
$$ \ln(1+h/y) = \beta_1\ln(1.01) $$
$$ 1+h/y = \exp(\beta_1\ln(1.01)) $$
$$ h/y = \exp(\beta_1\ln(1.01)) - 1 $$
$$ h/y = 1.01^{\beta_1} - 1 $$

This is the one which really surprised me. Ok sure, this might be reasonably well approximated by $\beta_1%$ for a $\beta_1$ close to $0$ but the error will quickly get significantly large if we deviate even a bit (e.g. $\beta_1 = 100$ gives us a true percent change of $170.48$% in y for a $1$% change in x but the approximation would have given us a $100$% change. That's quite the difference. Why not simply use $100$%$\times (1+p/100)^{\beta_1} - 1$ for an arbitrary change $p$% in $x$? Do we, in practice, just rarely encounter log-log regression coefficients that deviate this much from $1.01$?

Thanks for your thoughts!